# Is is possible to connect to exchange powershell online using azure-AD app ID/secret?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, exchange-server

Is it possible to connect to exchange powershell online using registered Azure application ID/secret which allows GraphAPI/EWS access?

FYI, I know how to do it with basic auth (username/password) as guided in MSFT website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 1):

it is currently possible to use the Microsoft Graph API to make calls to the exchange endpoint. However it's not the same thing as Exchange Powershell Online, please refer to the docs on the exchange graph api here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/office-365-rest-apis-for-mail-calendars-and-contacts

For more information on how to make calls via powershell, please look here : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2018/06/29/connecting-to-microsoft-graph-with-a-native-app-using-powershell/

You will also need to login with a user that has access to said exchange resources. If you login with an application/user that does not have permissions to access the exchange resources you will get a access denied error.

Comment: Sorry I think there is a confusion here. Let me rephrase my question:
I have a registered application in AzureAD which allows Graph API/EWS access. I basically use appID, secret, tenant ID to get accessToken and then call Graph API.
My question is :
 is it possible to use that appID and app secret to log-in exchange powershell online?
Is it must be work or school user account to authenticate with exchange powershell online?

Comment: So in regards to using only the app id and client secret (i.e. the client credential flow) it is not possible. The service principal would need to have been given explicit rights to access the exchange services. Per the issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10717
If you're interested in this feature please file it on feedback.azure and the product group will look into it as soon as possible. Also, please remember to mark this as the answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest try EXO V2 preview module to connect Exchange Online PowerShell using registered Azure application.

Step1: Get an OAuth access token using Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) PowerShell.

Step2: Create PSCredential object

```
$AppCredential= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(<UPN>,<Token>)
```

Step3: Pass the PSCredential to the EXO V2 module.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $AppCredential
```

Comment: What should be the UPN in step2, When I am using admin UPN I am getting error as password is too long. Also, passing ClientId as UPN is also not working.

Comment: As much as I would like for this to work for me, it does not. It lacks an organization and without the -app-id parameter it thinks it's a user. I don't actually think this code was tested and suspect that it's hypothetical. Further, with the current version being V3, if this worked in V2, it appears to have been deprecated.